# How to inherit the properties of two classes in one class?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms, location

I have a program which requires to inherit the properties of both broadcastreceiver and MapActivity.Actually I want to send current location (longitude and latitude) on receiving an sms from friend.I have a code with me but don't know how to inherit the properties of both the classes.Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/53ZJH3iN

Please give me some idea to solve this or any other approach if this is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

As java prohibits multiple inheritance,  you actually can not. As you are planning application for covert srveyliance,  you do not need any activity - just a broadcast receiver
which comunicates with location service and sends obtained location somewhere.

Comment: But my code uses locationmanager involving getsystemservice() which is showing error.Can you tell me how to modify my code to get longitude and latitude without inheriting MapActivity?

Comment: I fixed my code.Here is my updated code pastebin.com/yKitMftU But a new problem comes.Instead of sending its location(longitude and latitude) it is sending the sender's location which comes in message itself after sent from sender.I want this code to send location of receiver instead of sender.Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, but you can implement as many interfaces as you'd like so you can do this through composition.  Here is one rough outline, but there are many ways you could do it.  The basic idea is that for either or both of the classes that you want to inherit from you have a reference to some implementation and you expose the same interface through delegation to the actual implementation.

```
interface MapActivity {
   Coordinates getCoordinates();
...
}

class SomeMapActivityImpl {
...
}

class ReceivelocationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver implements MapActivity {
  private MapActivity mapActivity = new SomeMapActivityImpl();

  public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
    return mapActivity.getCoordinates();
  }

...
}
```